# Prone firing mechanic?

Tags: battlefield-3, call-of-duty-black-ops-2

So this method has been annoying the crap out of me for the past few weeks. You simply walk around and encounter an enemy. You start firing at them and they quickly go prone, and kill you in a matter of milliseconds. Is there a mechanic to this; why does this work so well? The game I'm pointing at is Black Ops 2, but I noticed this doesn't work in, for example, Battlefield.

What is the actual mechanic of drop shooting in black ops 2? So accuracy after x seconds, accuracy before. A nice answer would be an actual comparison featuring 2 guys both standing, then one start drop shooting and one simply starts shooting. Then a overview of damage dealt and overal accuracy.

Comment: Much of what is happening here is that going prone presents a smaller target for you to shoot.  From what I've seen, it works just fine in Battlefield; it's happened a lot to me in Battlefield 2.

Comment: @fbueckert i know that the mechanics for the games are different but lets just take black ops 2 for the question. Why do you actually fire more accurately if you go prone quickly?

Comment: Sorry, my skim of your question encompassed Battlefield 3 into the question as well; I've edited the comment.

Comment: Seems like bad design, mostly - surely in the half second or so as you're going prone your accuracy should be terrible. As it is, it looks like the devs apply the accuracy boost from being fully prone the instant you press the button, leading to cheesy tactics like this.

Comment: @Alex this is true however i also see a lot op players going prone and then immediately to crouch-position this gets the prone position registered and so (for a split second) giving the accuracy of being prone. Is this correct/noticed/being fixed?

Comment: I doubt it's high on their fix list...

Comment: Another advantage to dropshotting is the lag-compensation algorithm that everyone is so up in arms about. The end result of this is that your bullets are actually going to be shot 'in the future' by a fraction of a second. By dropshotting, anyone who is aiming at upper-chest/head will miss because you will be crouched/prone by the time the lag-comp has caught up.

Comment: Whatever it's called - it's a coward's way to play

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are referring to is sometimes called "drop shooting" or "dolphin diving" (the later one has some forward motion).

People do this because:

1) Shooters typically work like this - you go into crouching or prone position and your aiming reticule gets smaller, therefore you can shoot more accurate.

2) You yourself offer a smaller target. While true that you expose your head, you are still very small and hard to hit.

3) Quickly dive into cover.

Some games try to remedy this "phenomenon" by applying some penalties, like not being able to shoot while the "going prone" animation rolls (Battlefield 3), jumping very dramatically without the ability to shoot (Black Ops, other ones might as well, but don't know), or simply don't support prone (Battlefield Bad Company 2).

EDIT: Reading your comment - I don't know if someone has actually made something like that, but here are some youtube videos. Might contain something satisfying for you

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you are very close to what i was asking. My question is about drop shooting. Dolphin diving is a whole other subject. What is the actual mechanic of drop shooting in black ops 2? So accuracy after x seconds, accuracy before. A nice answer would be an actual comparison featuring 2 guys both standing, then one start drop shooting and one simply starts shooting. Then a overview of damage dealt and overal accuracy.